# jQuery - Insert text inside element of a HTML string

Tags: html, jquery, string, text, append

I store an html string into var HTML, which I get using the following:

```
var HTML = $('.group').get(0).outerHTML;
```

The output of HTML using console.log(HTML) is:

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="class1">
        Data123...
    </div>
    <div class="class2">
        <!--I want to insert text here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I want to insert some text inside the div class="class2". I am using the following code:

```
$(HTML).find('.class2').text("Hello!");
```

But now the output of HTML using console.log(HTML) is the same old HTML as before. The text "Hello!" did not get inserted. Can anyone help with the solution.

Here is the complete code:

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="class1">
        Data123...
    </div>
    <div class="class2">
        
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var HTML = $('.group').get(0).outerHTML;
$(HTML).find('.class2').text("Hello!");
console.log(HTML);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're updating a temporary DOM element, but that doesn't change the `HTML` string. You need to save the DOM elements in a variable.

```js
var new_div = $(HTML);
new_div.find('.class2').text("Hello!");
console.log($(new_div).html());
```